Ampere-Maxwell Equation & Non-Continuous Current
The Ampere-Maxwell equation suggests that current causes a circulating magnetic field, but there seems to be an assumption that current is continuous.
Current can obviously be modeled as continuous in most real-world situations, but isn’t real-world current really just a very large finite number of charges passing through an area per unit time? Current would then be 0 except at moments when charges are passing through, which would be represented with Dirac delta functions.
Does the Ampere-Maxwell equation not apply to situations like these where we are dealing with non-continuous currents? How could we find the magnetic field caused by a series of finite passing charged particles without assuming they are approximately continuous?

from $\nabla \times \mathbf H =\mathbf  J + \mathbf {\dot D}$ we have the $0=\nabla \cdot (\mathbf  J + \mathbf {\dot D})=\nabla \cdot \mathbf  J +\dot \rho $ becasue $\nabla \cdot \mathbf  D = \rho$. Consequently, $\mathbf J$ can be discontinuous because the local charge accumulation combined with the displacement current compensates for the current "jump" as it happens in every capacitor all the time.


there seems to be an assumption that current is continuous

There is no such assumption in Maxwell equations. The Ampere-Maxwell law could be written as
$$
\nabla \times \vec B = \mu_0 \, q \vec v_0 \,\delta (\vec r - \vec r_0(t)) +\mu_0\epsilon_0 {\partial \over \partial t} \vec E
$$
where $\vec J = q\vec v \, \delta (\vec r -\vec r_0(t))$ is the current density of a single charge $q$ in the position $\vec r_0(t)$.
The solution of Maxwell equations for a single point charge with arbitrary velocity is known as Liénard Weichert potentials, and the explanation of it could be found in The Feynman lectures of physics Volume II chapter 21 here. I suggest the reading if you want to know how to find in first place.
Now, to obtain the solution for a discrete distribution of moving particles is straightforward: if you know the fields for each of them, you know the total fields. But then what do you have? A so big and complex expression of fields that you have no intuition at all.

Does this imply that the induced magnetic field has an infinite value at points when a charge is passing through the surface? A finite number of infinitely valued magnetic fields would then be approximately equal to the continuous finite valued magnetic field we get when using a continuous current model?

Does it sounds strange to you? It's nothing different for the coloumb's Law. If you apply Coloumb's law for a point charge, you have a divergent electric field in the position of the charge. But the electric field  of an infinite plate uniformly charged is finite everywhere.

It makes sense to me now, but this is what was causing my initial confusion. Moving point charges seemed to contribute nothing to the magnetic field because there would be no current except at particular moments in time. I hadn’t considered that the magnetic field would have infinite magnitude at those moments, leading to a finite effect.
